# Adding Line separator (\u2028) into Logback pattern

Tags: logback, cloud-foundry, spring-logback

Tried to add custom Logback pattern in order to log Exception stacktraces into a single line (where new line character is replaced with unicode Line separator \u2028), as:

```
%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", UTC} %5p %t %c{5}:%L [log_framework=logback;app_name=${APP_NAME};app_version=${APP_VERSION};instance_id=${CF_INSTANCE_INDEX}] %m MULTIEXCEPTION %replace(%xException){'\n','\u2028'}%nopex%n
```

Note: See `spring-config.xml` config file in [Github](https://github.com/fabianlee/spring-music/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml)

In the console, `\n` is replaced, the Exception stacktrace is in one line but, instead with "Line separator" character (\u2028), `\n` is replaced with the string "u2028".

If I try to log directly this "Line separator" character (via Logback, as log message) - it is printed in the console correctly.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do this by entering the "Line separator" unicode character ( ) directly:

```
%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", UTC} %5p %t %c{5}:%L [log_framework=logback;app_name=${APP_NAME};app_version=${APP_VERSION};instance_id=${CF_INSTANCE_INDEX}] %m MULTIEXCEPTION %replace(%xException){'\n',' '}%nopex%n
```

Note: You can also manage to make Exception stacktraces "single-lined" in Spring Boot application by adding next application property:

```
logging.exception-conversion-word: "%replace(%xException){'\\n','\u2028'}%nopex"
```